# How to find the hour of the day when sales are highest for products in a .csv using pandas? And merge columns based on similar first name?

Tags: python, pandas

The .csv looks like this:

```
Date+time:         shirt      shirt (dress)  shorts  shorts (dress)  accessories
2019-01-01 5:00    5          3              2       2               3    
2019-01-01 5:05    1          1              4       1               5
2019-01-01 5:10    1          2              1       2               9
...
2019-12-31 11:55   5          2              1       1               7
```

I want to know if there is a way to combine the columns that share a common first name? For instance, the program should look for columns that share a similar first name such as shirt and shirt (dress), these should be merged together and considered one entity, same with shorts.

How would I go about finding the highest purchasing hour for each day of the year and then for those highest purchasing hours find the percentages of the total for each product?

Comment: You have two questions. I've answered one - please tell me if it worked, and then ask the other in a new Stack Overflow question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could trim off the second part of the columns, so that the ones with the same first name are changed to have the same whole name:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' ').str[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date+time:  shirt  shirt  shorts  shorts  accessories
0   2019-01-01 5:00      5      3       2       2            3
1   2019-01-01 5:05      1      1       4       1            5
2   2019-01-01 5:10      1      2       1       2            9
3  2019-12-31 11:55      5      2       1       1            7
```

Then, sum the columns with the same names together:

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
         Date+time:  accessories  shirt  shorts
0   2019-01-01+5:00            3      8       4
1   2019-01-01+5:05            5      2       5
2   2019-01-01+5:10            9      3       3
3  2019-12-31+11:55            7      7       2
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run this it only returns back the Date+time but all the other columns have disappeared.

Comment: I had done an edit to the date+time column before an changed it to_datetime and did a set_index method call on it. I removed those and reran this code and now no column names appear, Im using jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Also when I write ```print(df.columns.str.split(' ').str[0])``` I get back ```Index(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], dtype='object')```

Comment: And without doing the edits to Date+time I get back: ```Index(['Date+time', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], dtype='object')```

Comment: Another thing is that there are other columns that have 3 separate words in them.

Comment: Wierd. Will you please send the output of `print(df.sample(1).to_dict())`?

Comment: Found out that I had leading whitespace in my columns, so I did this to fix it: 
```df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' ').str[0]
new_df = df.groupby(level = 0).sum()
new_df.head()```
 ... new issue is that the columns appear like your first example but not summed together.

Comment: When I ```print(df.sample(1).to)dict())``` I get back the data correctly it appears, all single words and nothing repeated just like your final exmaple.

Comment: And I get this warning: ```UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.```

Comment: Okay. Is your problem solved? If it's still not, please send me the output of `print(df.sample().to_dict())` _before_ you run my code, i.e., on your original dataframe.

Comment: I get back this, the dataset is large: ```{'Date+time': {104830: '2019-01-01T02:20:00'}, 'accessories': {104830: 17795.6}, 'shirt': {104830: 4.6}, 'shorts': {104830: 1218.8}}```

Comment: So...I don't get it. `shirt (dress)` (for example) isn't in that output.

Comment: Dont know if it matters but when I run ```print(df.sample().to_dict())``` using ```strip()``` and ```split()``` that returns everything such as shirt and shirt (dress).

Comment: So have you got it figured out for this part?

Comment: Not yet. I rewrote a csv dataset exactly the way it is written above and this method isnt working on that either.