# How do you use pandas to find columns containing the name "add-on" and then append them to the previous column?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe looks like this:

```
date               pencils    notebooks   notebooks add-on   bookbag   bookbag add-on   pens
2020-01-01 5:00    12         5           3                  6         2                8
2020-01-01 6:00    10         7           2                  9         3                14
...
2020-31-01 23:55   18         4           6                  9         0                10
```

In pandas I want to find any column names that contains the word "add-on" and then sum that with the column before it. So for instance, `notebook add-on` since that contains the word add-on I need to append that to the column right before it named `notebooks`. The column `notebooks add-on` should no longer be a column name but combined/summed into the notebooks column. For example the result of the notebook column should look like:

```
   notebooks
   8
   9
   10
```

the same process should be true for any columns that contain the word "add-on". Columns that do not contain the word "add-on" should stay the same.

How would this be done in pandas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70240088, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70238922

Answer (score 0):

First make sure `date` is your dataframe index column, then remove the  `add-on` part of column names, then group columns and aggregate with `sum`:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' add-on', '')
print(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum())
```

Output:

```
                  bookbag  notebooks  pencils  pens
date                                               
2020-01-01 5:00         8          8       12     8
2020-01-01 6:00        12          9       10    14
2020-31-01 23:55        9         10       18    10
```